# Age from MySQL with filter

Tags: mysql

I need count persons with age > 60, but `MySQL` return 0. Please, help me.

```
SELECT
   count(*),
   TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE( ) ) AS age
FROM
   voluntario v
WHERE 
   v.id_status = 1
   HAVING age >= 60
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do this:

```
SELECT
   count(*),
   birth_date
FROM
   voluntario v
WHERE 
   v.id_status = 1 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE( ) ) >= 60
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your question doesn't work is because it is an aggregation query.  Hence the `having` is applied *after* the aggregation.  To filter *before* the aggregation, use a `where` clause.

That is easy enough to do:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM voluntario v
WHERE v.id_status = 1 AND
      v.birth_date < date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 60 year)
```

Note that the date arithmetic is performed on `CURDATE()` rather than on `birth_date`.  This allows an index containing `birth_date` to be used for the query (if appropriate).

Having `age` in the `SELECT` doesn't make sense, because there are (potentially) many different ages, and only one indeterminate value is returned by the query.